# contenteditable .execCommand() not firing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wysiwyg

Im experimenting on a custom WYSIWYG editor using contenteditable. I'm using the following code to make the selected text bold:

```
$('.wysiwyg-b').click(function() {
    document.execCommand('bold',false,true);
    alert('hi');
});
```

```
<li class="wysiwyg-b" title="Bold"><img src="images/icons/black/png/font_bold_icon&16.png"> </li>
```

And it looks like this:

[image: bold]

My problem is, the text is only made bold when I click on the image(B), not when I click on the blue surrounding area....but the alert does. What could be causing this issue?

Here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/3b4QM/
I changed the image to a B because the path was broken.

```
console.log(this)
```

returns

```
<li class="wysiwyg-b" original-title="Bold">
```

Comment: Posting a fiddle could help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I faced the same problem when I built up Froala Editor (https://froala.com/wysiwyg-editor). It happens because you loose the selection when you click the surroundings. Placing a button inside the `<li>` will solve the problem. Just make sure the button fits the entire `<li>`.

See http://jsfiddle.net/xdCjD/2/

In HTML:

```
<div id="apt-wysiwyg">
    <ul>
        <li class="wysiwyg-b" title="Bold"><button><img src="images/icons/black/png/font_bold_icon&16.png"></button></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

In CSS, remove the padding from li and set it to the button

```
#apt-wysiwyg li button {
    padding: 5px;
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px; 
    background: transparent;
    border:none;
}
```

Comment: Binding to 'mousedown' instead of 'click' would have solved your problem without the extra markup and css, but your solution reveals the different selection behaviour of li vs button very well.

Comment: I would prefer 'click' over 'mousedown', because in case of 'mousedown' if you click on the button and then move the mouse outside of it (while the button is still clicked), the event will have been fired. This is not something common.

Moreover, it would fire the event in case of right click too without additional verification.

Comment: This is what Barley uses?

Comment: Barley has it's own solution as far as I know. Most probably they use the same approach. I tried different ways of implementing this thing and I used buttons because it works on all browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Quick suggestion if you're writing it into the page after the page has loaded try:

```
$('.wysiwyg-b').on('click', function() {
    document.execCommand('bold',false,true);
    alert('hi');
});
```

Although you are getting the img to register the event so it might not help. Worth a shot anyway

Comment: Thanks but this produces the same issue.

Comment: _getting the a to register the event_ where is it?

Comment: sorry img tag. Still a bit early.

Comment: Its strange because it's alerting and confirms the event is firing, but the execCommand only works if I click on the image.

Comment: add a console.log(this) and click the blue area and img and see if you get different results than expected?

Comment: I get this  <li class="wysiwyg-b" original-title="Bold">

Answer (score 1):

What happens is that your editable text gets deselected when you click the `li` element. I think binding the event to mousedown will solve your problem:

```
 $(".wysiwyg-b").on('mousedown',function() {
        var test=document.execCommand('bold',false,true);
        alert(test);        
 });
```