# JQuery button click causes focus loss on highlighted text in editable div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a div which is editable and I am trying to format the text using buttons/anchors to trigger JQuery actions. The problem is that If I have a selected text inside the editable div and then if I click on `#bold` button to make it **bold**. The text loses focus and nothing happens to it.

## HTML

```
<div class="poster">
    <div class="editor" contenteditable="true" placeholder="What's on your mind?"></div>

    <div class="posterButtons preventCollapse">
        <div class="pull-left">
            <a id="bold">B</a>
            <a id="italic">I</a>
            <a id="underline">U</a>
        </div>
        <div class="pull-right">
            <a class="submitPost">Post</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

## JQuery

```
$('#bold').click(function(){
    document.execCommand('bold', false);
});
```

Comment: Remember the last selection on blur

Comment: Possible duplicate of [contenteditable .execCommand() not firing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21546993/contenteditable-execcommand-not-firing)

Comment: `<button type="button" id="bold">B</button>`

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef post that as an answer. It works! and pls explain why it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `<button>` instead of `<a>`

```js
$('#bold').click(function(){
    document.execCommand('bold', false);
});
```

```css
.editor {

    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding: 10px;
    outline: none;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="poster">
    <div class="editor" contenteditable="true" placeholder="What's on your mind?"></div>

    <div class="posterButtons preventCollapse">
        <div class="pull-left">
            <button type="button" id="bold">B</button>
            <button type="button" id="italic">I</button>
            <button type="button" id="underline">U</button>
        </div>
        <div class="pull-right">
            <a class="submitPost">Post</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

you can read [Why getting a text selection from textarea works when a button clicked but not when a "div" clicked (in Internet Explorer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7190606/why-getting-a-text-selection-from-textarea-works-when-a-button-clicked-but-not-w)

Comment: Would you please explain why button works and anchor doesn't?

Comment: @Feelsbadman I added a link which explain the idea of using `button` .. To be honest its not explain the concept well .. but this is what I have .. Have a great day :-)

Answer (score 1):

Please use `<button type="button" id="bold">B</button>` instead of `<a id="bold">B</a>`. Only use `<a>` tag if you have to redirect or something like that.

Also, if you are using a button as a submit button try to use `<button type="submit" id="bold">B</button>`. The difference is `button type` is just a button or submit button.

Comment: It'd be great if you could explain the behaviour of a button vs an anchor. That would explain why button **works** and anchor doesn't.

Comment: @Feelsbadman Basically anchor tag `<a>`  element represents a hyperlink to a destination page or a section within a page. Wherever the` <button>` element, more specifically the `<button type=“button”>` element, does nothing. Unlike other button types, such as the `<button type=“reset”>` which resets the form it is nested within, the `<button type=“button”>` does not have any default behaviour.